# Auto checkbox checked on page load based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated checkbox from database and output looks like

```
<label class="check" for="encs_1"><input data-size="33400361270" type="checkbox" name="encs[]" id="encs_1" value="1"><b></b><i>checkbox1</i></label>
<label class="check" for="encs_2"><input data-size="118062750" type="checkbox" name="encs[]" id="encs_2" value="2"><b></b><i>checkbox2</i></label>
```

There is anyway with jquery to automatically checked field after page loaded based on **data-size** so the field with the lowest value will be checked?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking a Yes/No question, the answer will be Yes. Please edit your post and indicate what you have tried or what script you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the input with the lowest `data-size` attribute by selecting all inputs, using [`jQuery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to extract the `data-size` attribute, then using [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```js
const min = Math.min(...$('input[data-size]').map(function(){ return $(this).data('size')}))

$('input[data-size="'+min+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="check" for="encs_1"><input data-size="33400361270" type="checkbox" name="encs[]" id="encs_1" value="1"><b></b><i>checkbox1</i></label>
<label class="check" for="encs_2"><input data-size="118062750" type="checkbox" name="encs[]" id="encs_2" value="2"><b></b><i>checkbox2</i></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using JavaScript.

Try this code:

```
<script>
const encs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='encs[]']");
var i = 0;   
for (i = 0; i < encs.length; i++) {
    if(encs[i].dataset.size=="118062750"){
       document.getElementById(encs[i].id).checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
```